# Autologin at boot on Ubuntu 20.04.2

Tags: boot, login

First Info, Ubuntu 20.04.2 Desktop Version Minimal installation with Packages that we need as Server.

This was done because of GUI was easier to install. Server is set to boot in Multi User without GUI. I need one User to automatic login and start GUI on tty6, tty7 would be better. I tried it with

```
systemctl edit getty@tty6.service
```

and rebooted. I get the message

> Service has more than one ExecStart= setting, which is only allowed for Type=oneshot services.

I can't figured out why, when I look in the "override.conf", I see only once. What am I missing to see here?

Answer (score 0):

I just had to add `ExecStart=` before the `ExecStart= ....` :

```
[Service]
# the VT is cleared by TTYVTDisallocate
# The '-o' option value tells agetty to replace 'login' arguments with an
# option to preserve environment (-p), followed by '--' for safety, and then
# the entered username.
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -a auto --noclear %I $TERM
Type=idle
Restart=always
RestartSec=0
UtmpIdentifier=%I
TTYPath=/dev/%I
TTYReset=yes
TTYVHangup=yes
TTYVTDisallocate=yes
KillMode=process
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
SendSIGHUP=yes
```